# Compile and Run C++ Application in Alpine Docker Container

Tags: c++, linux, docker, makefile, alpine-linux

I've been provided the source code from an older project in c++ and need to compile and run it in a Docker container running Alpine Linux.  I unfortunately don't have experience compiling in Linux or much with c++, with much google, I have tried to deploy a Docker container running Alpine Linux, install compile libraries/tools and try and compile using the make file, but I'm met with compile errors.  I can't provide too much details about the source code as its company property, but I can provide the makefile and the steps I've been taking:

install compile tools in Alpine Linux:

`apk update && apk add --no-cache autoconf build-base binutils cmake curl file gcc g++ git libgcc libtool linux-headers make musl-dev ninja tar unzip wget`

makefile:

```
BIN := testExec

# relative paths to all project source files
SRCDIR := src
INCDIR := include
IDEDIR := ide_files

# files included in the tarball generated by 'make dist'
DISTFILES := $(BIN).a $(BIN).dll $(SRCDIR) $(INCDIR) $(IDEDIR)

# filename of the tar archive generated by 'make dist'
#DISTOUTPUT := $(BIN).tar.gz

# cross-compiler name prefix
CROSS := i686-pc-mingw32-
#CROSS := /usr/local/gnat-x86_64-darwin/bin/

# toolchain executables
CC    := $(CROSS)gcc
CXX   := $(CROSS)g++
LD    := $(CROSS)gcc
AR    := $(CROSS)ar
RM    := rm
TAR   := tar
PERL  := perl

# path to script that generates ctags files
CTAGS := $(dir $(abspath $(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))ctags.pl

# output files generated by ctags
CTAGS_FILES := .tags .tags_sorted_by_file

# add other macro defines by calling make with a USER_DEFINES argument
#  e.g. [ make USER_DEFINES='BLAH FOO="bar"' ] will add the string "-DBLAH -DFOO=bar" to your CFLAGS
UFLAGS   := $(addprefix -D,$(USER_DEFINES))
DFLAGS   := -DBUILD_DLL

# debugging + major profiling
#DBGFLAGS    := -ggdb3 -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -gno-strict-dwarf -pg -Q -ftime-report -fmem-report
# debugging + minor profiling
#DBGFLAGS    := -ggdb3 -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -gno-strict-dwarf -pg -Q
# debugging
DBGFLAGS    := -ggdb3 -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -gno-strict-dwarf

# ensure the profiling flags get included for the compiler -and- the linker
CFLAGS   := $(DBGFLAGS) -Wall $(DFLAGS) $(UFLAGS) $(addprefix -I,$(INCDIR))
LDFLAGS  := $(DBGFLAGS) -shared -lm

# flags required for dependency generation; passed to compilers
DEPFLAGS    = -MT $@ -MD -MP -MF $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td
COMPILE.c   = $(CC) $(DEPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@
LINK.o      = $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@.dll -Wl,--out-implib,$@.a

PRECOMPILE  =
POSTCOMPILE = mv -f $(DEPDIR)/$*.Td $(DEPDIR)/$*.d

# source files
SRCS := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)

# intermediate directory for generated object files
OBJDIR := .o
# intermediate directory for generated dependency files
DEPDIR := .d

# object files, auto generated from source files
OBJS := $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%.o,$(basename $(SRCS)))
# dependency files, auto generated from source files
DEPS := $(patsubst %,$(DEPDIR)/%.d,$(basename $(SRCS)))

# compilers (at least gcc and clang) don't create the subdirectories automatically
$(shell mkdir -p $(dir $(OBJS)) >/dev/null)
$(shell mkdir -p $(dir $(DEPS)) >/dev/null)

.PHONY: all
all: $(BIN)

.PHONY: tar
tar: $(DISTFILES)
    $(TAR) -czpvf $(DISTOUTPUT) --transform='s|^|$(BIN)/|' $^

.PHONY: dist
dist: $(BIN) tar

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) -rf $(OBJDIR) $(DEPDIR) $(BIN).a $(BIN).dll

.PHONY: distclean
distclean: clean
    $(RM) -f $(DISTOUTPUT)

.PHONY: ctags
ctags:
    $(PERL) $(GEN_CTAGS) $(dir $(SRCDIR))

.PHONY: check
check:
    @echo no tests configured

.PHONY: help
help:
    @echo ""
    @echo " available make targets:"
    @echo "   all       - [DEFAULT TARGET] compiles and links all files"
    @echo "   dist      - creates a tarball containing sources and executables"
    @echo "   clean     - removes executables and object file directories"
    @echo "   distclean - same as clean and also removes dist tarball"
    @echo "   ctags     - creates ctags index files for entire project"
    @echo "   check     - performs verification on project (not implemented)"
    @echo ""
    @echo " NOTE:"
    @echo "   you can pass additional flags to the compiler using the USER_DEFINES"
    @echo "   argument given to make, e.g. [ make USER_DEFINES='BLAH FOO=\"bar\"' ]"
    @echo "   will add the string \"-DBLAH -DFOO=bar\" to your CFLAGS"

.PHONY: $(BIN)
$(BIN): $(OBJS)
    $(LINK.o) $^

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPDIR)/%.d
    $(PRECOMPILE)
    $(COMPILE.c) $<
    $(POSTCOMPILE)

.PRECIOUS = $(DEPDIR)/%.d
$(DEPDIR)/%.d: ;

-include $(DEPS)
```

The makefile references i686-pc-mingw32-gcc so I've attempted to install the package that matches: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=mingw-w64-gcc-base&arch=x86&repo=community For some reason I'm not getting the right files with the install though:

`apk add mingw-w64-gcc-base --repository http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community/`

```
bash-5.1# apk info -L apk add mingw-w64-gcc-base | grep usr/bin
usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-cpp
usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-11.2.0
usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ar
usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-nm
usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ranlib
usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcov
usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcov-dump
usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcov-tool
usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-lto-dump
```

So instead, I tried to install with the x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc, modified the makefile:

```
#CROSS := i686-pc-mingw32-
CROSS := x86_64-w64-mingw32-
```

The source code folder structure is:

```
/SRC/ide_files
/SRC/include
/SRC/src
```

the make file is:

```
/SRC/ide_files/testApp/makefile
```

I then try:

```
make -f ide_files/testApp/makefile
```

It errors with:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -ggdb3 -feliminate-unused-debug-symbols -gno-strict-dwarf -shared -lm  -o testExec.dll -Wl,--out-implib,testExec.a <A lot of .o files>

Error relocating /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld: qsort_r: symbol not found
collect2: error: ld returned 127 exit status
make: *** [ide_files/testApp/makefile:127: testExec] Error 1
```

Comment: One of the things that makes Alpine small is using a non-standard C library, but this can result in problems in particular with C and C++ programs, and once you're installing a full C toolchain the space savings are minimal at best.  Can you rebuild this on a Debian or Ubuntu base, with the more standard GNU libc instead?